# Converting CSV table to Wordpress Post Meta

Tags: mysql, wordpress, excel, csv

I've received a huge CSV file containing a table with all of the post_meta information for a Wordpress site.  These entries have their post ID matched up to the content, but aren't in a way I know how to upload.

If the first column of the table has the post_id and the first row of the table has the meta_key, is there a way I can sort this data into a postmeta file for the mySQL database?

Thanks!

Comment: What approaches have you already tried? What technologies are you into?

Comment: You have to prepare everything in Excel, then use a CSV import tool.

Answer (score 0):

WP Ultimate CSV Importer allows for the best importing. (trust me here) If a meta table exists it is available to assign a column to it per each row during import.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/